# Spring Rest: Handling client input errors identified at Domain layer

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, exception

I have a REST service for accounts. The controller calls the Service layer to find Accounts. AccountService can throw domain exceptions. It is usually a case related to client input error.In such a situation, I want to wrap the domain exception with ClientException. Is there a way that client can be presented with status code 400 and just the exception message? Or is there a better to handle the situation where the service layer detects an illegal argument?

```
@Controller
class AccountController
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/accounts/${accountId}")
    public Account account(@PathVariable int accountId, HttpServletResponse response){
        try{
            return accountService.find("Account not found with id: " + accountId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            response.setStatus(400);
            throw new ClientException(e);
        }   
    }
}

class AccountService{
    public Account find(int accountId){
        if(acountId > 100){
            throw new AccountNotFoundException(accountId);
        }else{
            return new Account(accountId, "someone");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a REST service, then simply setting the response status and a JSON body (with error message) should be enough. There's no real need to throw that ClientException.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an exception handler that takes the exception and marshals it into a JSON response object.

I did this some time ago, and it worked fine, however I know longer have the source-code to share. .

Look at Spring MVC's exception handlers as a starting point.